# Importing Android project into eclipse gives me two project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am importing the following project : ActionBarCompat-Basic from the Android Developers website into Eclipse.

by doing so: File -> Import => Android existing project.

However, in my package explorer, it creates me two projects :

1) The first project is named MainActivity

2) The second project is named tests.

Also, the two projects both have errors

Is that normal ? If yes, how can I solve the errors issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, because you do not say wich project you are importing, this a blind answer.

You get two project simply because in the downloaded folder are two project.

To resolve errors first of all try to do a clean Project=>Clean... and select the projects you want to clean.

Unfortunately errors are common when you import project coming from around the web. 
You should right click those projects, open Properties and check the Android tab, check if you are missing some library and try to figure out wich library is (or are).
Check Android 4.4.2 as build target.

Open the Java Build Path tab and open the Source tab, check if the gen and src folders are there, if not, add them.

If error are still there open the files marked with the error icon and try to figure out wich library they miss.

Check the Eclipse error Log.

I hope this help.

Comment: How can I check which library is missing for the project ? Is there a specific way to identify them ?

Comment: Quote from my answer:
open Properties and check the Android tab

Comment: Is it normal that there is nothing in red in the Android tab of Properties ? And the project isn't giving me error but when I try to open it in the emulator, it gives me an error saying : the application has stopped unexpectedly .

Comment: Now is time to check the LogCat ;)

read the error it reports, try to figure out what's goin on, it usually reference to the class wich generated the error, it also report the error codeline.

Sometimes is easy to understand what's going on, sometimes not.

If you can't figure out try to copy the errorlog line wich refer to your class and search the error on google or on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help :) I will mark the question as answered ! :)